Does Strep lay dormant in the body/throat after a successful course of antibiotics?
I (an adult) have had strep a few times this year. On two of those times, my dr prescribed Augmentin, which didn't work. So he gave me Clindamycin which did work (throat culture negative).
He then said that in the future I should not take Augmentin anymore. Why not?
If it's because the bacteria became resistant to Augmentin, why should it not work if I catch a strep infection again? Is it because the original bacteria lies dormant/inactive in the body ready to reinfect if the immune systems weakens? And having been resistant to Augmentin previously, it still is?
That view would be supported by this article, in which
Dr Hardy says:
"Unfortunately, yes, you can get strep throat again. What causes that is that sometimes the strep bacteria can remain in the tonsils even after the infection is treated. That person would become a carrier of strep. They might not have high enough amounts of strep to be sick, but that means if their immune system is put under stress, it could reactivate."
However, in this article, it is stated:
"Asymptomatic strep throat is also known as asymptomatic group A streptococcal carriage. It refers to a condition in which an individual has a bacteria called Group A Streptococcus (Streptococcus pyogenes) in their throat without actually experiencing any symptoms of strep throat....While asymptomatic carriers don’t require treatment for strep throat, they can serve as a reservoir for the bacteria and may inadvertently pass it on to others....Your immune system usually helps manage and eventually clear the bacteria from your throat over time. The risk of transmission to others also tends to decrease as the time you carry the bacteria lengthens, though there is still a possibility of spreading strep. This means a person can be a carrier of strep for much longer than the period of time they are contagious.
In fact, although it’s rare, lifelong carriage of the bacteria is possible. Some individuals may experience recurrent episodes of carriage, especially if they have repeated contact with the bacteria. If you are a strep throat carrier but do not have any symptoms, you will still test positive if you take a throat culture or rapid strep test."
This last sentence would imply that since my throat culture was negative, I did not have dormant strep. In which case the reinfection must have been external? But than why would Augmentin still not work the second time? especially seeing that Augmentin resistance isn't all that common.
Also, I work from home, so I don't really frequent public spaces. I also change my toothbrush, and clean all surfaces with purell, etc.
Furthermore, if it is true that it lies dormant, for how long? Does the body naturally ever eradicate it? Or does it stay indefinitely?

Hi and welcome. Did you search for an answer before asking here? Evidence of an attempt to solve the question (a quote and a link is fine) is required to be included in the question on this site. Pleaase use the edit button to include your results. If you tried but had no results, what search terms did you use? It's a good question, and it would be unfortunate to see it closed for lack of research.

@anongoodnurse Yes a ton of googling around. I'll include something.

You found a lot of good info, kudos! One last comment: do you have a partner/roommate/other with which you have routine conact?

@anongoodnurse Yes, family. I guess you'll say they may be a carrier? But the other family members arent catching it.

You just nailed it. If there's a carrier in your family (which is not terribly unlikely), until they themselves are tested and treated, or their carrier state changes (usually does with time), there will be a resevoir of the same Augmentin-resistant strep that you will continue to be exposed to. It's important to identify this member if you get sick repeatedly. That's why the "next time you get strep throat', you should be treated with the drug that worked. Hygiene is helpful, but if you're the mom/dad and a child is the carrier, that's really hard.

Children (ages 5-15) are the major reservoir for Group A strep (GAS) infections so identification of these carriers needs to be considered on the whole, to reduce the burden of GAS for you and for their community. This is something to discuss with your primary care provider. (great job on the research!)

Oh, finally, there may be factors particular to you that explain why you are more predisposed to get sick with exposure to GAS. Again, something to discuss/explore if you keep getting sick.

@anongoodnurse Ah I see, it is something to think about. We are all adults besides for an older child that tested negative for strep. What do you mean by "carrier state changes"? Do you mean the body will naturally eradicate the bacteria even though it is passive?

Yes, usually the carrier is capable of transmission for a relatively short time, like several months to a year (although there aren't hard numbers.) Rarely, there are lifelong carriers. If all are adults, simple good hygiene should suffice.

The beta-Lactam (B-lactam) family of drugs, which includes all the penicillin family, such as amoxicillin, as well as a bunch of other drugs such as cephalosporins and cephamycins all consist of a B-lactam ring and some side chains. Augmentin is made up of amoxicillin and clavulanic acid. In penicillin resistant bacteria, they produce something known as a B-lactamase, which is an enzyme that breaks the B-lactam ring and stops the drug from working. Clavulanic acid is not effective as an antibiotic by itself, but it is a B-lactam that effectively out-competes the amoxicillin for the B-lactamase and prevents the B-lactamase from breaking down all the amoxicillin, thereby allowing it to do its normal function and inhibit bacterial growth. You can read more about Augmentin and how the drugs work in a StatPearls Book1 at the NCBI. Having had a scan through the literature, it seems that Streptococci don't produce B-lactamases themselves.
There are a number of mechanisms of resistance to the B-lactam drugs and numerous reports in the literature for quite a few species, particularly Enterococci, there are no clinical reports of penicillin resistant Stretococcus pyogenes. However, the prevalence of resistance in Streptococcal infections is somewhere about 40% at the moment IIRC. It is thought that the primary mechanism of resistance in Streptococcal infections is through poor penetration of the drug into the tonsillary space, which means that not all bacteria get eliminated. There are also mechanisms controlled by the presence of other bacteria, which aren't affected by the drug, that allow the group A Streptococcus to grow relatively uninhibited, or enhance the attachment of the streptococci to the tissue and thereby allow better growth. You can read more about this topic in another StatPearls book2
Which mechanism you have, I obviously can't say, it would take testing at a laboratory specializing in this sort of bacterial physiology/ecology.  However, the general rule in treating infections is a 40:60 rule (or some variants like 50:50) where the rule is that the drug does its effect (the 40%), suppressing the bacteria until the immune system can get a handle on the bacteria and prevent further growth by itself (60%). In all cases there will be some bacteria left over after treatment. In the species that produce B-lactamases directly, they tend not to lose the ability to be resistant to penicillins, so it is likely that you will be forever more carrying these resistant bacteria in your body, but these will not be the S. pyogenes that causes your sore throat. However, there is some evidence that we naturally lose and gain populations of bacteria all the time, so you might well lose the S. pyogenes fully and be re-infected at some point. You will be a carrier for some period of time, until you lose the species, but it seems that life-long carriage of these species is rare.
We do transmit bacteria and bacterial traits from person to person, so much so that while in the normal (USA) population, about 0.9-1.5%3 of people carry Methycillin Resistant Staphylococcus aureus (MRSA) in their nasal passages, in a hospital population (e.g. doctors, nurses etc) this prevalence might be as high as 4.6%.4
Refs:

Evans J, Hanoodi M, Wittler M. Amoxicillin Clavulanate. [Updated 2024 Aug 11]. In: StatPearls [Internet]. Treasure Island (FL): StatPearls Publishing; 2024 Jan-. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK538164/

Cattoir V. Mechanisms of Streptococcus pyogenes Antibiotic Resistance. 2022 Sep 19 [Updated 2022 Oct 9]. In: Ferretti JJ, Stevens DL, Fischetti VA, editors. Streptococcus pyogenes: Basic Biology to Clinical Manifestations [Internet]. 2nd edition. Oklahoma City (OK): University of Oklahoma Health Sciences Center; 2022 Oct 8. Chapter 30. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK587098/

Turner, N.A., Sharma-Kuinkel, B.K., Maskarinec, S.A. et al. Methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus: an overview of basic and clinical research. Nat Rev Microbiol 17, 203–218 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41579-018-0147-4

Dulon M, Peters C, Schablon A, Nienhaus A. MRSA carriage among healthcare workers in non-outbreak settings in Europe and the United States: a systematic review. BMC Infect Dis. 2014 Jul 3;14:363. doi: 10.1186/1471-2334-14-363. PMID: 24996225; PMCID: PMC4094410.



Your answer, if I understand correctly, is saying that some bacteria will remain even after treatment in a dormant state. Wouldn't that make me a carrier? In which case I should test positive for strep? Or maybe there are too few bacteria for the culture to catch?

@user35687 Correct, some bacteria will remain. You may or may not be a carrier as the exact resistance depends on a few factors and some of them are associations with other bacteria, which might be transient in nature and would require transmission of more than one species to be a source. Sampling is a big issue for this, where, how, and when you take the sample can all affect the outcome of any test.

@user35687 I've added some more information and clarified a few things - you can compare the edits by clicking on the "edited X min/hour/day" bit directly below the full text.
